# better way to write if condition in javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, if-statement

I would like to know better way to check for `if` condition

Enter the `if` loop  if value not equal to null and value greater that equal to 0

Is there any way to write if condition to check for not null and number greater than 0

```
function checkCondition(value){
  if(value !== null && value >=0) {
    return "yes"
  } else {
    return "no"
  }
}
var result1=checkCondition(null);
var result2=checkCondition(2);
var result3=checkCondition(0)

Result
result1 no
result2 yes
result3 yes
```

Comment: What's the problem with that `if...else...`? The `else` is optional (because of the `return` in the `if`) but that isn't really a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just return the condition. Currently you are evaluating the condition, and if it's true return true, if it's false return false. That's just returning the condition with extra steps. `const checkCondition = value => value !== null && value >=0;`.

If you really want to return the words "Yes" and "No" instead, use a ternary :

```js
const checkCondition = value => (value !== null && value >=0) ? "Yes" : "No";

console.log(checkCondition(-8));
console.log(checkCondition(5));
```

It's just more compact and/or elegant, it's not faster or radically better than a good old `if...else...return`.

Comment: _"...and if it's true return true, if it's false return false"_ - OP returns strings that are not `true` or `false`.

Comment: Yes, I was editing my answer

Comment: And what makes your answer/a one-liner so much better, that it is worth to be posted?

Comment: I like one-liners

Comment: So that's just an opinion. Wasn't there something like a _"that's off-topic because it asks for opinion rather than objective answers"_ close-vote option?

Comment: Indeed, that might be more suited for CodeReview than Stackoverflow

Comment: why parentheses?

Comment: Because I suspect that without parentheses, the condition might be evaluated as `value !== null && (value >=0 ? "Yes" : "No")`. Better safe than sorry

Comment: for this problem the operator precedence is handy. it works without.

Answer (score 1):

```
function checkCondition(value){
  return (value !== null && value >=0) ? "yes" : "no";
}
```

Comment: why parentheses?

Comment: Suggested original code with ternary operator. It can be further minimised with arrow function and removing first condition as null > 0 will return false. 

const checkCondition = value => value > 0 ?  "yes" : "no";

Comment: no, because `null` is converted to zero and your check does not check zero as wanted.